# Hive SQL: Find the last time a user had an entry

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I am stuck a bit! I have a users table. The users get a score, but it doesn't come every day.

I need a way to show the score for the user for the last date that they got a score. It could be 1 month ago and I have 50M rows per day, so i can't just ingest all the partitions

Any idea how I can do this?

```
select userid, score from user_table where dt = 20201206
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the most recent record as below:

```sql
select userid, score
from
(select userid, score, row_number() over (partition by userid order by dt desc) as rn 
from user_table)
where rn = 1
```